# valgrind reporting "Invalid write of size 8"

Tags: c, valgrind, realloc

I'm trying to track down where valgrind is finding this invalid write of size 8 in some code, but am having a hard time seeing it.  I'm sure valgrind is correct, I just don't see it.  I've reproduced the original error by stripping out the function and doing the same thing, more or less, with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double* do_realloc(double* orig_graph, int graph_width, int* graph_allocated)
{
    double *graph = (double *)(realloc(orig_graph, (graph_width + 1) * sizeof(*graph)));
    printf("reallocing graph from %d to %d\n", *graph_allocated, graph_width);
    if (!orig_graph) {
        /* initialize */
        memset(graph, 0, graph_width * sizeof(double));
    } else if (graph) {
        if (graph_width > *graph_allocated) {
            /* initialize the new region */
            printf("old region: %p, new region: %p, offset: %d, length: %d\n", orig_graph, graph,
                 (*graph_allocated * sizeof(double)),
                 (graph_width - *graph_allocated) * sizeof(*graph));
            memset(graph + (*graph_allocated * sizeof(*graph)),
                   0,
                   (graph_width - *graph_allocated) * sizeof(*graph));
        }
    } else {
        printf("reallocing FAILED\n");
        graph = orig_graph;
        graph_width = *graph_allocated;
    }

    *graph_allocated = graph_width;
    return graph;

}

int main()
{
    double* graph = NULL;
    int allocated = 0;

    graph = do_realloc(graph, 307, &allocated);
    graph = do_realloc(graph, 300, &allocated);
    graph = do_realloc(graph, 307, &allocated);

}
```

And the valgrind output is:

```
$ valgrind ./t 
==4250== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4250== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4250== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4250== Command: ./t
==4250== 
reallocing graph from 0 to 307
reallocing graph from 307 to 300
reallocing graph from 300 to 307
old region: 0x51d4e60, new region: 0x51d5800, offset: 2400, length: 56
==4250== Invalid write of size 8
==4250==    at 0x4C348BE: memset (vg_replace_strmem.c:1094)
==4250==    by 0x4007A9: do_realloc(double*, int, int&) (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==    by 0x400842: main (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==  Address 0x51da300 is 16,672 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,185,600 in arena "client"
==4250== 
==4250== Invalid write of size 8
==4250==    at 0x4C348E6: memset (vg_replace_strmem.c:1094)
==4250==    by 0x4007A9: do_realloc(double*, int, int&) (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==    by 0x400842: main (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==  Address 0x51da320 is 16,704 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,185,600 in arena "client"
==4250== 
==4250== Invalid write of size 8
==4250==    at 0x4C348F3: memset (vg_replace_strmem.c:1094)
==4250==    by 0x4007A9: do_realloc(double*, int, int&) (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==    by 0x400842: main (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==  Address 0x51da328 is 16,712 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,185,600 in arena "client"
==4250== 
==4250== Invalid write of size 8
==4250==    at 0x4C348FD: memset (vg_replace_strmem.c:1094)
==4250==    by 0x4007A9: do_realloc(double*, int, int&) (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==    by 0x400842: main (in /home/dmcbride/tmp/v/t)
==4250==  Address 0x51da330 is 16,720 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,185,600 in arena "client"
==4250== 
==4250== 
==4250== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4250==     in use at exit: 2,456 bytes in 1 blocks
==4250==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 8,336 bytes allocated
==4250== 
==4250== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4250==    definitely lost: 2,456 bytes in 1 blocks
==4250==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4250==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4250==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4250==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4250== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4250== 
==4250== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4250== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The original code has much more than this, but I'm only trying to solve the first problem right now, and will continue investigating other problems after this.  I think this is related to the crash that the main application is having right after this point, every single time.

(Someone removed the "C" tag because I had left some C++-isms in, but that seems to me to be missing the purpose, so I removed all C++-isms and got the same results.)

Comment: If you compile with debug info then valgrind's output should include line numbers in your source code.  Best to compile with optimizations disabled, too, while trying to sort this out, but do watch out for the possibility that some problems only appear in optimized code.

Comment: Nevertheless, given that you get four errors coming from `memset()` calls in `do_realloc()`, that narrows the search space substantially.

Comment: Your pointer arithmetic is wrong. `graph + (*graph_allocated * sizeof(*graph))` should be just `graph + *graph_allocated`.

Comment: And indeed, it looks like you have errors in your pointer computations in the second `memset()` call.  Remember that pointer arithmetic operates in units the size of the pointed-to type.  You're computing the starting address incorrectly.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile, Most likely your original code is also full of problems.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value to a temporary pointer and check that pointer for NULL,  if not NULL, then assign to the actual target pointer.  Otherwise the original pointer will be lost, resulting in an unrecoverable memory leak.  3) do not cast the returned value.  the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the posted code fails to pass the memory allocation pointer to `free()`, so there is one of the problems.

Comment: The posted code is using `int` parameters and local variables but the `realloc()` function is expecting `size_t` variables.  This might not matter for these small a values, but the compiler will complain on every such 'implicit conversion' that it has to do if the `-Wconversion` parameter is used at compile time

Comment: this line: `(graph_width - *graph_allocated) * sizeof(*graph));` will result in a negative number when increasing the size of the graph allocation.  Probably not quite what you want

Comment: this parameter to the `printf()` statement: `(*graph_allocated * sizeof(double)),` yields a `size_t` value and it is being (mistakenly) forced into a `%d` format specifier.  Suggest using: `%lu`

Comment: @kaylum - please post as an answer. I've been staring at this code for days without seeing that.  Thanks.  (For the record, this isn't my code, it's in code I want to run, but it keeps crashing, and this is, if not the full answer, at least the big one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my analysis of the posted code,

The problem is in the call to `memset()` (which goes along with most of the valgrind error messages.)

Where writing a `sizeof(double)` beyond the end of the allocated memory area.

And failing to pass the allocated memory to `free()` before exiting the program.